# How to return reference to variable with single return statement

Tags: c++

Consider the following snippet.

```
MyType_t& Variable(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return MyVariable0;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        return MyVariable1;
    }
    return MyDefaultVariable;
}
```

This will return a reference to a variable that can then be modified.

```
Variable(1) = 10;
```

However, our coding standard says to use a single point of return. How would I accomplish this? For some reason, the following seems to only copy the value (thus not returning a reference to the root variable), even though I've verified stepping through code it sets `var` to the appropriate variable.
This would be simple with pointers, but I just can't get the references right.

```
MyType_t& Variable(int i) {
    MyType_t& var = MyDefaultVariable;
    if (i == 0) {
        var = MyVariable0;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        var = MyVariable1;
    }
    return var;
}
```

---

*Notes*

The returned variable has a global scope (its on an embedded system).

The function is used as a convenience method inside a class, with very limited use/scope.

Comment: You would accomplish this by taking the coding standard and lighting a barbecue with it.

Comment: Once a reference is bound, it can not be re-bound to reference something else. And a reference must always be initialized (bound) to something, so you can't leave it uninitialized. In short, you have an impossible requirement conflict.

Comment: 1) One cannot change the reference, in such a way, that it refers to a different variable, after its initialization. 2) Gotta love those arbitrary coding requirements, that make the code both harder to write, and harder to read..

Comment: Single point of return is dictated by Misra C++, and burning the standard will not help.

Comment: @T'n'E - In this particular case, it will. Because that particular rule is dumb af. When you return early, the function is done. It cannot accidentally change state that will affect the result before doing the "real return". Consider the fact that if you use a pointer, like in one of the answers bellow, and your conditions are not **perfect**, the value of the pointer may change. This rule allows bugs to creep in and makes debugging harder, since you need to keep stepping through and keeping state in your mind until the function exists. It deserves to be burned.

Comment: Not to mention that single point of return can lead to pretty bad spaghetti code and maintainability nightmares.

Comment: @StoryTeller This is not a question if the rule is dumb or not - the rule _is_ there and I _have_ to comply it. Even if I print a thousand copies and burn them. (Probably, I'll then be fired and not have to deal with it, so maybe you're right...)

Comment: @T'n'E - Alright. Put the logic in a `do {} while(0);` and `break;` after the setting the pointer. I believe MISRA C++ is fairly relaxed about `break`-ing out of loops? I mean, it's not as clear as early return, but if complying with the standard is of utmost importance...

Comment: Hah, found it. 6-6-5: *"A function shall have a single point of exit at the end of 
the function"*. Well, I'm negatively surprised.

Comment: The [*historical* meaning](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118793/126524) of "Single Entry, Single Exit" was approximately "Don't mess with the calling convention" That it morphed into "don't use more than one `return`" is misunderstanding a rule because the language doesn't support breaking it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reference is bound to `MyDefaultVariable` and you cannot modify it afterwards, because that's how it works. Your `var = MyVariable0;` effectively called `MyDefaultVariable`'s copy operator, which results in the behavior you observed.

If you want to avoid using a ternary operator here, you can use something close to what you suggested, but using a pointer later dereferenced within the return statement.

```
MyType_t& Variable(int i) {
    MyType_t* var = &MyDefaultVariable;
    if (i == 0) {
        var = &MyVariable0;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        var = &MyVariable1;
    }
    return *var;
}
```

Comment: Explained the underlying issue, provided a solution that solved the problem and did not suggest something that was out of scope of the question. Exemplary answer!

Answer (score 4):

If you want your function to remain readable while adding more variables, I would discourage the use of reference/ternary operators. Pointers would be the way to go.

```
MyType_t& Variable(int i)
{
MyType_t* var = &MyDefaultVariable;

if (0 == i)
    var = &MyVariable0;
else if (1 == i)
    var = &MyVariable1;

return *var;
}
```

Comment: "_I don't see why people bring in ternary operators._" Because OP understood that one could do it with pointers, but wanted solution with references: "_This would be simple with pointers, but I just can't get the references right._"

Comment: "I don't see why people bring in ternary operators" how else do you choose between more than one option that you want to bind to a reference? Unless you write what OP has orignially (and if you dont want to further obscure the code by using a pointer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the conditional operator :

```
MyType_t& Variable(int i) {
    return ( i==0 ) ? MyVariable0 : ( i==1) ? MyVariable1 : MyDefaultVariable;
}
```

However, a coding standard that forces you to write unreadable code does not deserve to be called "coding standard" imho.

Answer (score 0):

std::reference_wrapper will provide this functionality without exposing you to the risk of raw pointers. using reference_wrappers also expresses intent.

Note that assigning a new reference to a std::reference_wrapper will cause the wrapper to rebind, it will not overwrite the contents of the referred-to variable.

```
#include <functional>

using MyType_t = int;
extern int& MyDefaultVariable;
extern int& MyVariable0;
extern int& MyVariable1;


MyType_t& Variable(int i) {
    auto var = std::ref(MyDefaultVariable);
    if (i == 0) {
        var = MyVariable0;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        var = MyVariable1;
    }
    return var;
}
```

Another way to express this would be:

```
MyType_t& Variable(int i) 
{
    auto var = std::ref(MyDefaultVariable);
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0: var = MyVariable0; break;
        case 1: var = MyVariable0; break;
        default: break;
    }
    return var;
}
```